# How to interpret the results of a logistic regression in python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, p-value, coefficients

When I run a logistic regression using sm.Logit (from the statsmodel library), part of the result looks like this:

[image]

The variable y is academic success (average greater than 10). The problem is that I am lost in front of this table (there is only the beginning), I do not know how to interpret the results. In the coef column, can I interpret only the sign or the value too? For "absences" I can say what with -0.0459? Also what does column "z" mean and what can I say on it? The confidence interval I understood but the beginning is quite blurry for me, can you help me please?

Comment: I think you should ask your question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) forum.